# Erro do sonnar Nas Classes Java - adicionar Copyright

Tags: java

Estou tratando um erro no Sonnar e apareceu um erro em todas minhas classes para adicionar no Header um Copyright.

**Add or update the header of this file. **
Já fiz isso mais o erro continua.
Meu codigo é esse.

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * * Copyright (c) {DATE} {INITIAL COPYRIGHT OWNER} {OTHER COPYRIGHT OWNERS}.
 *  * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 *  * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 *  * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 *  * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 *  *
 *  * Contributors:
 *  *    {INITIAL AUTHOR} - initial API and implementation and/or initial documentation
 *******************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Olha, não entendo ao certo o que você está fazendo, mas onde estão os dizeres `{DATE}`, `{INITIAL COPYRIGHT OWNER}`, `{OTHER COPYRIGHT OWNERS}` e `{INITIAL AUTHOR}`, você não deveria preencher com as informações pertinentes?

Comment: Não sei, essa é uma duvida também. 
será é preenchido automático?